# AndroidStudio - Navigation Editor Linking

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have latest AndroidStudio , I am trying to make a navigationeditor link between two layout. But I am unable to do so, the GUI shows no option to link. Can you help?

The main.nvg.xml content is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<navigationModel
  ns = "http://schemas.android.com?import=com.android.tools.idea.editors.navigation.model.*">
  <locations  
    class = "java.util.ArrayList">
    <statePointEntry>
      <state      
        class = "com.android.tools.idea.editors.navigation.model.MenuState"      
        xmlResourceName = "menu_activity20"/>
      <point      
        x = "2708"      
        y = "480"/>
    </statePointEntry>
    <statePointEntry>
      <state      
        class = "com.android.tools.idea.editors.navigation.model.MenuState"      
        xmlResourceName = "menu_main"/>
      <point      
        x = "1760"      
        y = "320"/>
    </statePointEntry>
    <statePointEntry>
      <state      
        class = "com.android.tools.idea.editors.navigation.model.ActivityState"      
        className = "com.example.test.Activity20"/>
      <point      
        x = "1440"      
        y = "480"/>
    </statePointEntry>
    <statePointEntry>
      <state      
        class = "com.android.tools.idea.editors.navigation.model.ActivityState"      
        className = "com.example.test.MainActivity"/>
      <point      
        x = "160"      
        y = "160"/>
    </statePointEntry>
  </locations>
</navigationModel>
```

GUI on IDE looks like this http://postimg.org/image/7n7kymv7f/

Android original doc on how to use AndroidStudio's navigation editor is not of much help.

-Rajdev

Answer (score 1):

From http://tools.android.com/navigation-editor

> "Add transitions from controls (e.g. Buttons and menu items) to other Activities - by shift-dragging with the mouse (ctrl/alt also work)"

Comment: If you are on Mac: Shift  an drag OR command + option(alt) click the Button, menu and drag ...